# Can't find ScalaSig for class java.lang.Object

Tags: scala, json4s

Didn't find the answer in these topics: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269645/cant-find-scalasig-for-class), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638220/cant-find-scalasig-for-class-json4s-with-scala-proguard-for-an-android-app)

Have the next problem. I have a case class named Foo:

`case class Foo(a: Int, b: List[Int])`

When I need to make an AST of this class I invoke `Extraction.decompose(<instance of Foo>)` and get an AST represenation of foo instance.

But if I make field `b` as private

`case class Foo(a: Int, private val b: List[Int])`

I get `org.json4s.package$MappingException: Can't find ScalaSig for class java.lang.Object` exception.

This is only true for private fields that are collections.

If private field is simple object it simply doesn't get appeared in AST.
Why this exception does happen?

**EDIT**
The same exception arises if I have a case class extending some trait with val or lazy val fields:

```
trait Bar {
   val list: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
}

case class Example(field: Double) extends Bar
```

Comment: Try for bigint instead of int.

Comment: I asked not about how to fix this, I asked about why this does happen. Have to mention that this works with String

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is the similar to the issue that I'm running into.

First, [ScalaSigreader#42](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.6/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/reflect/ScalaSigReader.scala#L42)

```
if (current == null)
```

should be

```
if (current == classOf[java.lang.Object])
```

Then, you'll get a more helpful error message: "Can't find field b from Foo".  But this by itself doesn't fix the issue.

I haven't looked into a fix for the private field issue.  However, I do have a fix for the issue with the interface.  For that problem, [ScalaSigReader#45](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.6/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/reflect/ScalaSigReader.scala#L45) needs to be modified.

Currently if the field isn't found then the superclass is searched:

```
findField(findClass(current), name).getOrElse(read(current.getSuperclass))
```

The interfaces must be searched as well:

```
findField(current, name)
    .orElse(current.getInterfaces.flatMap(findField(_, name)).headOption)
    .getOrElse(read(current.getSuperclass))

private def findField(clazz: Class[_], name: String): Option[MethodSymbol] =
    findField(findClass(clazz), name)
```

See also:

[Issue #403](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/403)

[Pull #436](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/pull/436)